# Dockerized nginx cannot load certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, jenkins, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to dockerize nginx with ssl. In Jenkins console output I see this error:

> PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)

When I check ssl with these commands

```
openssl x509 -in test.crt -text -noout
openssl rsa -in test.key -check
```

Everything looks fine.

Here's my files;

Docker-compose:

```
proxy:
    build:
      context:  .
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt:/etc/nginx/nginx.crt
      - ./etc/ssl/certs/nginx.key:/etc/nginx/nginx.key
      - ./etc/ssl/certs/nginx.csr:/etc/nginx/nginx.csr
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - corp
```

domain.com.conf:

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name test.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx.key;
```

Comment: Can you (or did you) run the `openssl` commands within the container? The file names you used are also different than the code blocks but I assume you may be hiding your actual file names.